# Bundle/CopyJavascript Libraries from Node_Modules (.Net Core proj with TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, backbone.js, webpack, bundle

This question might be trivial and easy for a lot of people, but I am having a hard time configuring everything to work properly, would like to learn how this works.

I want to create a client side project in VS2015, however I want to use TypeScript and also some external javascript libraries, like backbone and marionette.

I already configured most of the things, but when running the page I see an error on the console saying 'Marionette is not defined', which makes me think that the libraries (that I previously installed on the project using NPM) are not being copied to wwwroot correctly.

I am using Webpack with a loader to transpile my TypeScript files.

Can someone guide me on the right path? or maybe send me some documentation please?

**Here is my package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "yourappname",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "ts-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "webpack-script": "webpack"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "webpack-script"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/backbone": "^1.3.42",
    "@types/backbone.marionette": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "backbone.marionette": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

**My webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict"
{
    // Required to form a complete output path
    let path = require('path');

    // Plagin for cleaning up the output folder (bundle) before creating a new one
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    // Path to the output folder
    const bundleFolder = "wwwroot/bundle/";

    module.exports = {
        // Application entry point
        entry: {
            app: ["./Scripts/main.ts"],
            underscore: ['underscore'], 
            jquery: ['jquery'], 
            backbone: ['backbone'], 
            backbonemarionette: ['backbone.marionette']
        },

        // Output file
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, bundleFolder)
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.tsx?$/,
                  loader: "ts-loader",
                  exclude: /node_modules/,
              },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder])
        ],
        // Include the generation of debugging information within the output file
        // (Required for debugging client scripts)
        devtool: "inline-source-map"
    };
}
```

**My tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,

    "alwaysStrict": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es5",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],

    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true
  },

  "include": [ "./Scripts/*" ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

**My main.ts**

```
class MarionetteApp extends Marionette.Application {  //That's the thing not defined in chrome console 'Marionette'
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.on("start", this.initializeAfter);
    }
    initializeAfter() {
        console.log("i am here");
        alert("initialiseAfter called");
    }
}
```

However from the chrome console, there seems to exist a file there, as you can see here:

[image]

Another thing I notice is that, I see a warning in the Dependencies folder in VS and also the Marionette it has a syntax error, it's not defined, why? Here:

[image]

Please can someone give me insight on this? what am I doing wrong?
Willing to learn how to do it properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Webpack.ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) to define globals

```
 const Webpack = require('webpack');
//...
 plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder]),
    new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          _: 'underscore',
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          Backbone: 'backbone',
          Bb: 'backbone',
          Marionette: 'backbone.marionette',
          Mn: 'backbone.marionette',
      }),

  ]
```

Also get rid of the multiple entry points, like so

```
entry: "./Scripts/main.ts",
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, does this mean that I dont need anymore to reference those libraries on my html file? How does this works under the hood? webpack copy the library javascript files? that would mean that I still need to reference it on my html.

Comment: Simply reference  <script src="./bundle/main.js"></script>

Comment: Webpack has bundled your code (main.ts) and your dependencies (jQuery, Marionette etc.) in that single file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, will test it in a minute and accept your answer, btw do I need to configure something extra in Webpack to transpile my TypeScript files?

Comment: Sure let me know how it goes . I see you're using ts-loader in your webpack config. That should take care of the transpilation.

Comment: Hey @gawicks I dont have the Marionette is not defined error, but now I still have the MarionetteApp is not defined, why? any idea? I tried adding the 'export' on the class, but I got another error :s

Comment: The code you posted only has the declaration of 'MarionetteApp' . Where are you using it?

Comment: To test the class, I have this on my index.html: <script type="text/javascript">
  var marionetteApp = new MarionetteApp();
  marionetteApp.start();
 </script>

Comment: I see . That's the problem , you can't do that

Comment: Move class MarionetteApp to a another file and "export" it. And then "import" it to main.ts. Then your test code can go inside main.ts.

Comment: Treat "main.ts" as your entry point, any testing /consuming code should go inside there.

Comment: Thanks I notice that using "extends Marionette.Application" is using the full library right? That's why I get errors running the webpack build like this: "WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit. this can impact web performance." I should only import only the class Application from Marionette namespace to avoid this error, is that right?

Comment: So I can't use normal inline javascript code in my html that refers to some class in typescript file? I though the transpiler would compile the class and it would be available to use as inline javascript code

Comment: To use it inline, the module has to be "imported" . Such a thing will require the transpiler to run inside the html inlined code. Which I haven't tried.

Comment: it's working now! great! thanks! will accept your answer now, however can you tell me about the warning I got ? my bundle.js is huge (1mb), I think it's loading everything from that library, its possible to load only that class?

Comment: Let me see . If you dont want them avaiable globally, you could try import { Application} from "backbone.marionette" instead; But depending on the library this may or may not do much.

Comment: I already did that (and deleted the provided plugin section, however it didn't reduce the bundle size) =/

Comment: FYI, There are other options to reduce bundle size . If you're interested experiment with something like UgilfyJS.

Comment: Okay thanks @gawicks ! I am trying to understand the purpose of "new Webpack.ProvidePlugin", I though that the point was using globally the variable "Marionette" but I always get the error "refers to a umd global but the current file is a module. consider adding an import instead" so I added the import using "import { Application } from 'backbone.marionette' " and I have no error anymore, however I can just delete the ProvidePlugin on config... so what is that for? thanks man!!